# bnlearn package: unexpected cpdist (prediction) behaviour

Tags: r, bayesian, bayesian-networks, bnlearn

I encounter a problem that goes beyond my understanding.
I have made a simple reproducible example for you to test it out.

Basically I create a Bayesian network with two strongly correlated variables that are linked together. One would expect that if one of them is high, the other one should also be (Since they are directly linked).

```
library(bnlearn)

Learning.set4 = cbind(c(1,2,1,8,9,9),c(2,0,1,10,10,10))
Learning.set4 = as.data.frame(Learning.set4)
colnames(Learning.set4) = c("Cause","Cons")
b.network = empty.graph(colnames(Learning.set4))
struct.mat = matrix(0,2,2)
colnames(struct.mat) = colnames(Learning.set4)
rownames(struct.mat) = colnames(struct.mat)
struct.mat[1,2] = 1

bnlearn::amat(b.network) = struct.mat
haha = bn.fit(b.network,Learning.set4)

# Here we get a mean that is close to 10    
seems_logic_to_me=cpdist(haha, nodes="Cons", 
                                evidence=list("Cause"=10), method="lw")

# Here I get a mean that is close to 5, so a high value 
# of Cons wouldn't mean anything for Cause?    
very_low_cause_values = cpdist(haha, nodes="Cause",  
                                 evidence=list("Cons"=10), method="lw")
```

Could anyone enlighten me here on the reason why it doesn't work with the `lw` method? (You can try with `ls` and it seems to work fine).

`lw` stands for likelihood weighting

UPDATE:
Got the solution from the maintainer.
Adding the following at the end will print the the expected prediction:

`print (sum(very_low_cause_values[, 1] * attr(very_low_cause_values, "weights")) / sum(attr(very_low_cause_values, "weights")))`

Comment: I kind if feel this may be a stats question regarding how likelihood weighting is implemented, but I'm not sure, but hopefully someone can answer

Comment: hello user 20650. I sent an email to the maintainer of the package who could answer me. adding
 `print (sum(very_low_cause_values[, 1] * attr(very_low_cause_values, "weights")) / sum(attr(very_low_cause_values, "weights")))` will do the trick, and give me what I want. (It's indeed a question of weighting)